# Calling jquery function in external js from jsp in my spring mvc app

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I want to link my jquery(jqplot) function in external js file to my jsp but the chart is not generating when i do this.

Is this problem arising because i am getting data dynamically through JSTL in `${finalscorepercent}`

my jquery code in external.js

```
$.jqplot.config.enablePlugins = true;

var d1 = ${finalScorepercent}
var d2 = 100 - ${finalScorepercent}

var data = [
    ['FinalScore', d1],
    ['f', d2],

];

var plot4 = $.jqplot('finalScorepercent', [data], {

    seriesDefaults: {
        // make this a donut chart.
        renderer: $.jqplot.DonutRenderer,
        rendererOptions: {
            fillToZero: true,
            // Donut's can be cut into slices like pies.
            sliceMargin: 3,
            // Pies and donuts can start at any arbitrary angle.
            startAngle: -90,
            /*  showDataLabels: true,  */
            // By default, data labels show the percentage of the donut/pie.
            // You can show the data 'value' or data 'label' instead.
            /* dataLabels: 'label', */
            // "totalLabel=true" uses the centre of the donut for the total amount
            totalLabel: true,
            showDataLabels: true,
            dataLabels: 'value'

        }
    },
    grid: {
        background: 'transparent',
        borderColor: 'transparent',
        shadow: false,
        drawGridLines: false,
        gridLineColor: 'transparent',
        borderWidth: '0'
    },
    seriesColors: [
        '#57c1b4', '#bd66a9',
        '#abb3b6'
    ],
    negativeSeriesColors: ["#498991", "#C08840", "#9F9274"],
    highlighter: {
        show: true,
        useAxesFormatters: false,
        tooltipAxes: 'xy',
        formatString: '%s:%s'
    }


});
```

here is my jsp code

```
<div id="finalScorepercent" style="height: 200px; width: 200px;">
<script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value="/views/js/external.js">">                                     
</script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`${finalscorepercent}` is a JSTL statement, it will not be rendered as `Number` in JavaScript file, thus your code doesn't work.

You can create a JavaScript variable in the Template file which can be used in *external.js*,

*HTML*

```
<div id="finalScorepercent" style="height: 200px; width: 200px;">
<div>
<script>    
    window.finalScorepercent = ${finalScorepercent};
</script>
<script src="<c:url value="/views/js/external.js">">                                        
</script>
```

Now in `external.js` file, you can use `window.finalScorepercent` instead of `${finalScorepercent}`

```
var d1 = window.finalScorepercent;
var d2 = 100 - window.finalScorepercent;
```

Comment: yes..error: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) of the path of external js file

Comment: i corrected the path ...now getting this error in browser console...Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'formatString' of undefined ..http://localhost:8090/Sarthak/views/js/jqplot/jqplot.pointLabels.min.js